# Concatenation Full Name with Miss Ms in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

My Question is that i have one option set which is Gender inside two option Male and Female and one field Fullname. I want that when i select male inside option set the full name is concate with ms and when we select female full name is concate with miss

Comment: The answers below are not supported in Dynamics context. Are you trying to update the field value in DB itself or some label for display purpose?

Comment: Actually i wanted only logic and its working..

Comment: fullName = firstName + ' ' + middleName + ' ' + lastName;
    formContext.getAttribute("cms_fullname").setValue(fullName);

    if (gender == 175650000) {
        fullName = "Miss" + ' ' + fullName;

        formContext.getAttribute("cms_fullname").setValue(fullName);
    }

    else if (gender == 175650001) {
        fullName = "Ms" + ' ' + fullName;

        formContext.getAttribute("cms_fullname").setValue(fullName);
    }

Comment: ok then, upvote/accept the answer helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I applied this code and now it's working
==================================================
```

```js
function GenderValidation(executionContext) {
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  var FullName, gender;
  if (formContext.getAttribute("cms_fullname") != null) {
    var FullName = formContext.getAttribute("cms_fullname").getValue();
  }

  if (formContext.getAttribute("cms_gender") != null) {
    var gender = formContext.getAttribute("cms_gender").getValue();
  }
  if (gender == 175650000) {
    FullName = "Miss" + ' ' + FullName;

    formContext.getAttribute("cms_fullname").setValue(FullName);
  } else if (gender == 175650001) {
    FullName = "Ms" + ' ' + FullName;

    formContext.getAttribute("cms_fullname").setValue(FullName);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said and I understand you could try storing the two in variables and concatenate them like below. However It would be difficult to advise without code snippets.

```js
let title = document.getElementById("title");
let fullName = document.getElementById("fullName");
let titleAndFullName = title + fullName;
```

Comment: Yes..but i am using xrm inside javascript.

Comment: As other contributors have previously said we cannot help without an appropriate example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have jQuery restriction you can use:

```js
$("input:radio").click(function() {
  console.log($("input[name='Gender']:checked").data('name')+" "+$("input[name='fullname']").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> <input type="radio" name="Gender" data-name="Mr" checked="true">Male</label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="Gender" data-name="Ms">Female</label>
<input name="fullname" type="text" />
```

But if you do need to use pure javascript then you can use:

```js
function check(){
var options = document.getElementsByName("Gender");
var fullname = document.getElementsByName("fullname");
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].checked){
             console.log(options[i].getAttribute("data-name") + " "+fullname[0].value);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<label> <input type="radio" name="Gender" data-name="Mr" checked="true" onclick="check()">Male</label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="Gender" data-name="Ms" onclick="check()">Female</label>
<input name="fullname" type="text" />
```

Comment: Gender is an option set inside two option Male and Female..i am using dynamic crm

Comment: Do you have any example of how you're storing them? Since you can just concatenate once you got the value

Comment: Actually i am new in javascript and dynamic crm..Through example i will explain you ...i have two field one is option set type of field Gender (inside two option Male and female)and another one is full name type of field which is string..My question is that when i select male then full name is concate with Ms+Fullname(Ms abc)and when i select Female then full name is concate with Miss+Fullname(Miss def)

Comment: Below just i am trying..but its not correct only for the example purpose.......function ConcatenateName() {
    var name = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cms_fullname").getValue();

    var Title = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cms_gender").getValue();

    if (Title = Male) {

        name += Ms;

    }

    else {
        name += Miss;
    }
    
}

Comment: @ShefaliMishra Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55015514/edit) that info to the original post? [With additional info as to which part wasn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.

```
if (selectedOption == "male") {
    document.write("Mr. " + fullname);
} else if (selectedOption == "female") {
    document.write("Miss " + fullname);
}
```